# How can i build images with php?

Tags: php, facebook, image-processing

I want to get user images from his facebook account and using PHP create images based on that.

I.e. http://en.nametests.com/test/result/eligijus/py_2423530448/

Is there a php library for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [php GD images functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Here an example that add a transparent watermark to an image (:

```
<?php
    // Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

    // First we create our stamp image manually from GD
    $stamp = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 70);
    imagefilledrectangle($stamp, 0, 0, 99, 69, 0x0000FF);
    imagefilledrectangle($stamp, 9, 9, 90, 60, 0xFFFFFF);
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');
    imagestring($stamp, 5, 20, 20, 'libGD', 0x0000FF);
    imagestring($stamp, 3, 20, 40, '(c) 2007-9', 0x0000FF);

    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    // Merge the stamp onto our photo with an opacity of 50%
    imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50);

    // Save the image to file and free memory
    imagepng($im, 'photo_stamp.png');
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Credits goes to [the official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php). You can use these functions to merge images, change sizes, format, add text, shapes, drawings, etc...